# Why can't I connect to the internet on ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu

I have just installed ubuntu 20.04, I was running the 18.04, formated the disk, and made a clean install of windows 10 and ubuntu (I am dual booting), however, for some reason I can't connect to the internet, I am using an ethernet cable though. I have explored around 15 answers here, Reddit and github, but none seems to work, I cant run ifconfig, because I need to install the net-tools, which I can't without internet. Any guesses? My internet is working on windows, so this is 100% a ubuntu problem

Comment: It's a power issue. There are lots of duplicates of this. Edit the turn off wifi option in Windows and it'll be solved

Comment: Thank you!!! That did it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check with the LAN cable? If it is work then there is an issue with wife driver.Just Run this command on terminal.

sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1"

Comment: Hey man, thank you a lot for your comment, I solved it by disabling the wifi.
Thank you